# C program that prints the string inversely

Tags: c, string

I have a problem, I want to read a string and display it inversely

**Example**
(if the user entered "Table" the program should respond like this)
e
le
ble
able
Table

but with my code it is being displayed like this
e
el
elb
elba
elbaT

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[100];
    int i,w;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets( str,100,stdin);
    int s=strlen(str)-1;
    for(w=s-1;w>=0;w--)
    {
        for(i=s;i>=w;i--)
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should start by writing some code.

Comment: Most importantly, this is not a code-writing service. You present what you have, describe a relatively narrow problem you have with your code, and we will try to help you with that problem.

Comment: You should work on your inner loop. If you think it logically the outer loop is controlling number of characters to print and the inner loop the order of characters. So changing inner loop should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop prints the characters backwards. If you don't want that, don't do this, and instead do

```
for (i=w; i<=s; i++)
{
  printf("%c",str[i]);
}
```

You could also remove the inner loop and simply print the rest of the string, starting at `w`:

```
for(w=s;w>=0;w--)
{
    printf("%s\n", &str[w]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char str [] = "Table\n";
int slen = strlen (str) - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= slen; i ++)
{
    printf ("\n");
    for (int j = slen - i; j < slen; j ++)
    {
        printf ("%c", str [j]);
    }
}
```